# How can I automate inserting items into specific inventory slots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

[image: Nuclear Reactor Picture]

This is my nuclear reactor, I have a chest and a hopper connected to the top. I want to import items into the chest (or the reactor directly) so that the reactor is always full.
However, I need to do this so that the pattern of the cells and heat vents remains the same, is this possible?

Comment: you can leave the vents and plates in place right?

Comment: well the issue is the vents and other components will eventually wear out and then leave an empty space, which if i only automate IN cells will result in cells going to places where the vents are

Comment: then create a mark1 reactor which you can leave on indefniately

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm not asking how to use or have an easy to manage reactor, I'm asking what the title of the question states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Advanced Electric Buffer](http://ftbwiki.org/Advanced_Buffer) item was practically designed to do exactly this task. The item is introduced by gregtech, and it inputs items into specified slots into machines.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use computercraft turtles for this automation. Programmed correctly, they can insert objects from a selected inventory slot of the turtle into a certain chest. Connecting that and the thermal/energy sensors from Nuclear Control, you can determine what the reactor needs eg. output is down so add uranium, heat is increasing so replace vent/exchanger. It may be necessary to remove everything and reinsert in the correct order if more than one part wears out simultaneously. Play around with it, this is the fun part.

Comment: Using turtles for that is unnecessarily complicated. Assuming the sensing is done well, is reliable, and doesn't suffer from race conditions, it would be easier to simply have a chest for each component and use the sensing trigger to pull from the right chest into the reactor.

Comment: it's the only mod that will potentially be able to access the actual inventory correctly, also the lua sandbox doesn't race with the world; the code runs until a yield-like operation happens after which the world will update to the next tick

Comment: +1, Because while this is too complcated for the OP's question, it is very useful to others. Becasue people forget it can be done
when thinking slots and all else fails try computer craft (Esp with OpenPeripherals), with such a system I automated the filling of galactic craft oxygen tanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am wrong, the vents and (heat exchangers?) should never be moved at all. So all you would have to deal with is the uranium cells and the near-depleted uranium that they sometimes create which makes it pretty simple in that you just need to pipe the cells in and pipe out the near depleted uranium.

You can do this with either emerald pipes (not sure if in this version) or AE which both let you choose exactly what to pipe in/out.

Comment: well the issue is the vents and other components will eventually wear out and then leave an empty space, which if i only automate IN cells will result in cells going to places where the vents are